# Recreating useState custom Hook in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a useCustomState hook which I want to work exactly in the same way as useState hook. I wrote the below code but the setState is not working.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

const useCustomState = (initialState) => {
  let value = initialState;
  function setValue(newVal){
    value = newVal
  } 
  return [value, setValue]; 
}

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useCustomState(3)


  return (
    <>
      <h1>{state}</h1>
      <button onClick={()=>(setState(state+1))}>Increment</button>
    </>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

The state shows as 3.
But button does not change state to 4.
What went wrong in my code?

Comment: Your custom hook doesn't have any state.

Comment: There's nothing here which would cause the component to re-render.  Just setting a new value to a variable doesn't do this, which is why we have state in the first place.  Taking a step back, what exactly are you trying to accomplish by *avoiding* `useState`?

Comment: Or what is `useState` not doing that you need it to do?

Comment: You cannot simply recreate the `useState` hook, there are a lot of key features that would be a pain in the a** to recode, so why bother ? You can create a custom hook if you want to, but you still need to use the react hooks inside it

Comment: Or if you're trying to understand how `useState` works you could also check out https://www.netlify.com/blog/2019/03/11/deep-dive-how-do-react-hooks-really-work/ *(with the caveat that I haven't vetted it beyond scanning it)*.

Comment: @DaveNewton I find this article misleading. It's more about closures then about how react `useState` works. I expected an explanation of how components are rerendered etc.

Answer (score 0):

Like other comments have mentioned, you should try to use **useState** for this purpose unless you have a very specific reason not to. The great thing about **useState** is that you can set it to represent anything you want. It can represent primitive types, like booleans and integers, or it can even represent an object type or array. In your example, you are trying to use an integer as a state, which is a case where you should use useState rather than trying to make your own custom state.

If what you are trying to do is create a "custom state" so you can set your state to something outside of a primitive type that might be a bit more complex, refer to [this React documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-objects-and-arrays-in-state). The first example here shows the user with a state that uses an object representing form fields. For more complex **useState** situations, consider using objects or arrays, rather than making a custom hook.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Here's the updated code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const useCustomState = (initialState) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);

  const setValue = (newVal) => {
    setState(newVal);
  };

  return [state, setValue];
};

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useCustomState(3);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{state}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setState(state + 1)}>Increment</button>
    </>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```